# Unable to load home icon in html code using font-awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>WEbsite</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css"
        />
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <header class="header">
          <nav class="nav-bar">
              <a href="#home"><i class="fa-regular fa-house"></i>  <span>home</span></a>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Unable to load home icon in html code using font-awesome. In place of home icon, browser showing a cross icon. Kindly, tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you change fa-regular to fa-solid?

Comment: Hello John, do you have the Pro Plans for using Regular Icon? Check this link: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/add-icons/how-to#basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fa-solid` instead of regular.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>WEbsite</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <a href="#home"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>  <span>home</span></a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @johndavis `fa-regular` is for pro plans only using a see-through transparent house icon. `fa-regular` is for the free plan included with font-awesome. You can see on [this page](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/add-icons/how-to#basics) that fa-regular is for pro plans only, and regular is for free.

Answer (score 0):

The Fontawesome icon is loaded fine, but you're using the wrong classes.
Replace
`<i class="fa-regular fa-house"></i>`
to
`<i class="fa fa-house"></i>`